# Looping and echoing a specific line comes out as blank?

Tags: php

There is a text file that my PHP script is meant to loop through. It is meant to echo only lines that are not *end*.

This is how my text file looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gil5.png

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php
   $contents = file("combo.txt");

   foreach($contents as $line) {
     if ($line !== "end") {
       break;
       echo $line;
     }
   }
?>
```

I'm confused why it echoes blank spaces. Could someone help me out?

Comment: what is your output now?

Comment: just a blank output

Comment: You have `break;` before the `echo`.

Comment: remove the `break;` and try again

Comment: i know i want it to break after it finds one

Comment: `file` leaves the line break characters at the end of the read lines (until you explicitly tell it otherwise), so apart from maybe the last line, none of them will be _equal_ to `end`.

Comment: how do i prevent that? should i use *fopen*?

Comment: You can use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` as part of the `file()` calls

Comment: honestly, i think that's the best answer yet. its much more efficient, and it causes less hassle.

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```php
<?php
$contents = file("combo.txt");

foreach($contents as $line) {
  $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);;
  if ($line != "end") {
    echo $line; 
    break;
  }
}
?>
```

**output**

```
1
```

I change the place of the `echo` with `break` 
You should first `echo` what you want and then `break` it 
And if you look at the `$line` there is one `\n` so I remove it and it work now

Comment: true but now it outputs *end*

Comment: I update my answer, it works now, check it out

Answer (score 0):

You should chop off anything (probably a newline) after the 3 chars you are testing for. Also I tested for `end` and only when I find one do I break the foreach loop, otherwise the line gets printed.

```
foreach($contents as $line) {
    if (substr($line,0,3) == "end") {
        break;      
    }
    echo $line;
}
```